# Magento extremely slow when activating SSL

Tags: magento-1.9, performance, ssl

we have a Magento 1.9 site wich ran quite fine (we integrated it into a Joomla-site with Magebridge, but the performance-problem is not related to that, why, i explain afterwards).
If we try to activate SSL in Magento, the site runs extremely slow, the main request takes about a minute).
I tried to access the magento-page without magebridge, its exactly as slow.
I already deleted all magento caches and checked the htaccess for redirects.
The magento administration is fast however...
Is there any way to debug what magento is doing whilst loading?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The Profiler is what you need, it will show you all routes taken to load the page and the speed/resource taken by each function.

I highly recommend this article on Atwix to learn more about how to use it:
https://www.atwix.com/magento/finding-bottlenecks/

On a side note, have you tried loading a page such as a `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` test.php page via your SSL configuration, to ensure it's not a server configuration issue?

**Edit:** After reviewing the site, it turns out a full reindex was required after changing of URLs. Once full index done, different store views load as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, we are looking into profiling at the moment.. Already spent some hours debugging an profiling the app yesterday =/

Comment: Happy to take a look for you. My email is contact@rickymatthews.com

Comment: Hi Ricky, thanks for the offer, i tried to send you an email, but the host does not seem to exist... =/

Comment: @pixx sorry, was in the midst of renewing the domain last night, should work if you try again today

Answer (score 0):

One possible explanation is that FPC is disabled for secure pages. This extension can help with that.

https://github.com/elastera/EnterprisePageCacheSSL

Answer (score 0):

If Varnish is included as part of your setup, then it's likely that SSL connections are bypassing Varnish (as Varnish and SSL aren't officially supported to work with one-another).

Ref: https://varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/phk/ssl.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but no, we do not use varnish caching ;-)